# C++ Custom Functions with commas vs semicolons

Tags: c++

So far I have been writing my own functions where my arguments are separated by comma's, but is there a way to write a function with semicolons instead of comma's? If so, what is the reason for wanting to do that? I guess when I look at the for-loop statement, its arguments are separated by semicolons and I don't understand that. I am just trying to understand the small things in C++.

Thanks--

Comment: Why would you want to write C++ code that isn't C++ code? `for` isn't a function, it's a control structure.

Comment: You need to pick up a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) on C++.

Comment: Why not read a book on C++ instead of seconding guessing the language

Comment: Programming Principles and Practice using c++ by Bjarne Stroustrup and C programming language by K&R

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact in the for loop statement each part of the sstatement is a separate expression statement. So it is naturally that they are separated by semicolons.
Its parts are defined as

```
for-init-statement  
condition;  
expression
```

Even the condition is considered as a statement because there apart from all there can be a declaration. Moreover each part can contain either a list of expressions (separated by comma) or the comma operator. So the only way to distinguish each part is to use the semicolon.

Consider the following for loop

```
for ( size_t i = 0, j = std::strlen( s ); i < j; i++, j-- ) std::swap( s[i], s[j] );
```

if do not use the semicolon it would be difficult to write the similar statement that to understant where each part ends or starts.

As for function parameters then you deal with a list. In the C++ grammar items of a list are separated by commas that to distinguish them from statements.